# How to install poker-eval on CentOS

Tags: linux, unix, centos, debian

Kind of a super noob in Linux here.
How do I download poker-eval on CentOS?

The default page is this: https://packages.qa.debian.org/p/poker-eval.html
which confuses me much.

And I also found this via google: https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/nibbler/poker-eval/ but I'm confused how to use this Copr thing.

Edit: I tried downloading using the following:

```
rpm -ivh poker-eval-134.0-1.fc6.i386.rpm 

rpm -ivh poker-eval-debuginfo-134.0-1.fc6.i386.rpm

rpm -ivh poker-eval-devel-134.0-1.fc6.i386.rpm
```

But I can't figure out where the running script is.
Here are the files I found using `find / -name "*poker*"`

```
/usr/include/poker-eval
/usr/include/poker-eval/poker_defs.h
/usr/include/poker-eval/poker_config.h
/usr/include/poker-eval/poker_wrapper.h
/usr/include/poker-eval/pokereval_export.h
/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/libpoker-eval.so.1.0.0.debug
/usr/lib/libpoker-eval.so
/usr/lib/pkgconfig/poker-eval.pc
/usr/lib/libpoker-eval.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib/libpoker-eval.so.1
/usr/src/debug/poker-eval-134.0
/usr/src/debug/poker-eval-134.0/include/poker_defs.h
/usr/src/debug/poker-eval-134.0/lib/poker_wrapper.c
/usr/share/doc/poker-eval-134.0
/usr/share/doc/poker-eval-devel-134.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the official project page is actually at http://gna.org/projects/pokersource/

The first page you listed is the debian downstream project page.
The second page you listed seems to be an unofficial build of python bindings for poker-eval on CentOS.

You can try installing via these RPMs:

http://download.gna.org/pokersource/poker-eval/gnulinux/fedora/f10/src/redhat/RPMS.poker-eval/

- poker-eval - the shared library binaries for use in apps
- poker-eval-debuginfo - the shared library binaries debug symbols for use with gdb
- poker-eval-devel - header files for compiling code against the library for use in apps

Note that poker-eval is just a library for use in different apps.
For more information, see http://pokersource.sourceforge.net or the contents of /usr/share/doc/poker-eval-134.0 you mention up above.

Or you could build from source yourself:

1. Download the appropriate source archive:

   `wget http://download.gna.org/pokersource/poker-eval/gnulinux/fedora/f10/src/redhat/SOURCES/poker-eval-134.0.tar.gz`
2. Extract the archive:

   `tar -axvf poker-eval-134.0.tar.gz`
3. Go into the extracted archive:

   `cd poker-eval-134.0`
4. Build the binaries

   `./configure && make && sudo make install`

Comment: Am I supposed to download all three rpm files and run "rpm -ivh file.rpm" for each file?

Comment: @user2911983:  That depends on your needs.  I updated my answer with more details on each file.. and yes rpm -ivh file.rpm would work

Comment: Where is the installation destination if you use rpm? I used the command and got 100% bar thing in the command line, but I can't find anything related to poker-eval except the rpm file

Comment: Actually i found files using "find / -name "*poker*", but still don't know where the directory is for running it. I'll update the info on my post

Comment: I updated my answer to provide a more thorough explanation based on what you have installed.  The important thing to note is that the poker-eval is only a library.  There is nothing to execute unless you install something that actually uses it or compile your own application that uses it.